# Dynamically change CSS rules in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dynamic, stylesheet

I'm looking for a way to change the CSS rules of my stylesheet imported in the document. So I have an external stylesheet and some `class` and `div` attributes inside. I want to change one of the rules with JavaScript or jQuery.

Here is an example :

```
.red{
    color:red;
}
```

So the idea is to do something in JavaScript and the HTML knows that now the `color` is another color like this:

```
.red{
    color:purple;
}
```

But I want to have this rule for every element that I add in the future by the way of append. So if I add a `span` with the CSS class `.red`, the text has to be purple and not red.

I hope I made it clear.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You jQuery [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css) method to do that.

```
$('.red').css('color', 'purple');
```

For multiple rules:

```
$('.red').css({
    'color': 'purple',
    'font-size': '20px'
});
```

When you add dynamic element in future to DOM by the way of append, just give those element some `class` or `id` and write `CSS` rules like above after appending them and they will applied for all dynamically created element.

### **[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/KXDJE/3/)**

#### Note

Add dynamic rules is not a good solution in my point of view. Instead of the you can load some external `CSS` file.

But if you need something like dynamic rules add method then:

```
$('head').append(
  $('<style/>', {
    id: 'mystyle',
    html: '.red {color: purple }'
  })
);
```

And for future use:

```
$('#mystyle').append(' .someother { color: green; font-size: 13px } ');
```

### [Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/KXDJE/6/)

Comment: Will this satisfy "But I want to have this rule for every element than I add in the futur by the way of append" ?

Comment: You need a comma after 'myrule', I think. Surely that last part makes the .css() stuff redundant?

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't work (at least in Chrome). You need to add `.red { color: purple; }`, not just `color: purple;` to the style tags. Doing so would stop the `append()` from working, too (unless you appended a second .red declaration, I guess).

Comment: It works perfectly !! Thanks again !! This is exactly what I needed thanks you again !! Sorry for this late response but I was not in front of my computer !! Thanks you again !!

Comment: BTW, I tried with .css before posting the question but it didn't works so I wanted to override my css and see if it could works ! :) Thanks again @thecodeparadox !!

Comment: This is wrong as already explained by @Grim. It only changes the color for existing elements. The above answer injecting style into <head> does the right thing.

Answer (score 23):

You can inject style declarations into the DOM.

```
$("head").append('<style>.red { color: purple }</style>');
```

Comment: Doing this is generally a bad idea IMO, but I'll upvote as it does exactly what the OP wanted, adds style to all elements, including future ones added to the DOM at a later time.

Comment: Interesting - why do you think it's a bad idea - because it's hard to reverse?

Comment: @Grim... it can also be hard to track down: depending on the complexity of the JS, it can be really hard to debug why something is not appearing the way you expect it to.  There are some cases where this is useful though--I came to this question because I needed to know how to do this for a Greasemonkey script...

Answer (score 9):

If you want to add a rule, instead of editing each element's style directly, you can use [`CSSStyleSheet.insertRule()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule). It takes two parameters: the rule as a string, and where to insert the rule.

Example from the above link:

```
// push a new rule onto the top of my stylesheet
myStyle.insertRule("#blanc { color: white }", 0);
```

In this case, `myStyle` is the `.sheet` member of a `style` element.

As far as I can tell, the `style` element must be inserted into the document before you can grab its sheet, and it can't be an external sheet. You can also grab a sheet from `document.styleSheets`, e.g.

```
var myStyle = document.styleSheets[1]; // Must not be a linked sheet.
myStyle.insertRule("#blanc { color: white }", 0);
```

Note: The page recommends modifying elements by changing their classes, instead of modifying the rules.